# How can i see dotnet implementation code (for eg.UseAuthentication() middleware) in vs code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

when i press crl+right click in app.UseAuthentication() in vs code it only open the interface class but not actual implementation.

```
app.UseAuthentication();


//this will open the following class

#region Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
// Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll
#endregion

#nullable enable


namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Extension methods to add authorization capabilities to an HTTP application pipeline.
    public static class AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Adds the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware to the specified
        //     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder, which enables authorization
        //     capabilities.
        //     When authorizing a resource that is routed using endpoint routing, this call
        //     must appear between the calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...) for
        //     the middleware to function correctly.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   app:
        //     The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder to add the middleware to.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A reference to app after the operation has completed.
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder app);
    }
}
```

i'm aspecting the actual implementation service class

Comment: Maybe there is an extension that supports this, but I wouldn't know of any. For such advanced scenarios you may need to install Visual Studio, it is and will always be more advanced for things like this. All editions including [VS Community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) can do this.

Comment: You can raise feature requests, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues or help implement that. But there isn't much more to discuss.

Comment: Instead of installing Visual Studio you could also use https://source.dot.net Just input the interface name in the search bar and it will jump to its source code. If you then click on the interface name it will list all implementations (and usages), which you can then select to view their source code and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For the ASP.NET Core source code you can find it on [github here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore).

For your current `AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions`, you can check its source code in the following reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.cs